# how to download large file using Curlwget extension

Tags: wget

I have added the CurlWget extension for my browser  and tried to download data using jupyter notebook as below:

```
 !wget --header="Host: storage.googleapis.com" --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
 Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36 
 OPR/66.0.3515.44" --header="Accept: 
 text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,
 application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" --header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -- 
 header="Referer: https://www.kaggle.com/" "https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/competitions
 /4117/46665/train.7z?GoogleAccessId=web-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1580049706&Signature=kowWRCMZZkqsrEqcwFtNJd4nwGgpE9DLbAcJ2b%2BvaGw1Wie82k3K03bhmHpqnhIKPsloHQJRq%2FHpBxv4kSeINAymvKvJXcpffjMqx%2Baujazoqxbl0aAQUhBs27OTKTqSp5Hzfhpz%2FKd%2Fx6SuYUCxy7x%2BAFOjlzQ8se59vJPwEmRNr4%2BSeOepC%2F%2BWJYzgLIcXDFy%2BUjjH1SrnBdAgRiMEa8pPD%2FZxmRma4ggWIWskLEVyuq4oAyVnaXK%2F39GsCo5lr199KqsPsO7BYJxs2hGv%2FlY6n4PirdQpw68dsSrLvfnSbpQckVVRtqjb9uLWDsQqarWfec1INAmHwaa%2B2Db2yQ%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3Dtrain.7z" -O "train.7z" -c
```

But i am getting below error:

```
'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

i have installed wget using below command:

```
pip install wget
```

Comment: That will only install the Python wget package. Do you have Wget installed on your system as well?

Comment: @darnir yes i have installed wget on my system

Answer (score 0):

This probably not a satisfying answer, but the answer is `don't do this`. CurlWget was flagged as malware and taken from the chrome web store:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/curlwget/jmocjfidanebdlinpbcdkcmgdifblncg/support?hl=pt-BR&authuser=2

Comment: i got the solution on how to download files using wget but as you correctly mentioned it is now been taken from chrome